# How to encode an image to display it in browser

Tags: c#, ajax, image-processing, asp.net-mvc-4

I have alot of images saved in a folder on server side, the database has the url of each one and the client cannot open the images directly because of permisson. My problem is how can I encode the image to display it in browser from server?

This is the code i have in the action result that search for the image:

```
public FileResult SearchImage()
{

    var path = @"\\jesus-pc\Frontera\IMAGENES\SINGNOS DISTINTIVOS\0\80HP23891268272.TIF";
    var img1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);

    return File(im1, "image/jpg");
}
```

The image exists but this is what is displayed:

[image: Image not loading]

I tried with  **Convert.ToBase64String(img1)** but I got this error:

```
the server responded with a status of 414 (Request-Uri Too Long)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Update:

My bad that I did not write the whole code of what I'm doing.

The last part that did not mentioned was that im using ajax to call the image.

When the user sends a request for information, there will be a link that will open a modal box. Inside that modal box is where the image must be displayed but the image will be loaded using ajax because the page should not be reloaded. So the image will be requested with ajax. Here is my code:

```
$(".doc").dblclick(function () {


$.ajax({
    url: "mainpage/SearchImage",
    data: "",
    type: "post",
    success: function (data) {
        ModalWindow.open();
        document.getElementById("img_1").src = data;
    }

})
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `FileStreamResult` instead of `FileResult`?

Comment: @DenysDenysenko No, its says that i cannot convert FileContentResult to FileStreamResult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `FileStreamResult` instead of `FileResult`. This should solve your issue.
The code shou look something like:

```
public FileStreamResult SearchImage()
{

    var path = 
       @"\\jesus-pc\Frontera\IMAGENES\SINGNOS DISTINTIVOS\0\80HP23891268272.TIF";
    var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    return new FileStreamResult(fileStream, "image/jpeg");
}
```

Another thing that takes my attention is mime-type specified. In filename it's `tif` but in code it's `jpeg`.

**Update**

Why are you using ajax for this? You can do something like this instead:

```
$('#img_1').attr('src', 'mainpage/SearchImage');
```

Comment: No, its says that i cannot convert FileContentResult to FileStreamResult

Comment: @user2195741, you also have to change result type of the action.

Comment: What you mean by changing the actionresult type?

Comment: @user2195741, see my code sample. And also check the mime-type. Maybe it should be `image/tiff`.